# Is it possible to integrate iPhone Photos Edit options to a custom app

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, photos

Is it possible to integrate iPhone's Photos Edit option to your own application as follows?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can edit library photo in custom app and can save it in library as different image but the actual library photo can not be modified.